# Scrollbar now appearing in Firefox, not in any other browser. Just started July 5th

Tags: facebook, firefox, canvas, scrollbar

This is a firefox specific bug that just started today.   IE and Chrome do not show any scrollbars.  I'm making all the appropriate Facebook calls to autogrow the page.

I have in place
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
FB.Canvas.setSize(true);

Inserting css: Overflow : hidden on the html tag will fix the problem but breaks many of my pages.
and nothing is working.   Even with css: Overflow:hidden the vertical/horizontal scrollbars still appears but is disabled.

Previously, firefox had always displayed a disabled bottom scrollbar, but now it is displaying a enabled vertical scrollbar as well.    The vertical scrollbar just crept up over night and is now displaying on the live version of my app.  Something changed on the Facebook end to have the vertical scrollbar start showing up.

Aside from the vertical scrollbar now appearing, firefox also displays a disabled bottom scrollbar that is impossible to get rid of, I've seen this bottom scrollbar on every app on facebook in Firefox.

You can see the bug live in action by going to 
apps.facebook.com/Ovrlap-App   I also went around checking out other FB apps and found another example on BranchOut (an app with 2mill + users).

Firefox has always had a disabled bottom scrollbar which I'm totally clueless as to how to get rid of it.   But this new vertical scrollbar just showed up today.

Thanks in advance,
-Rob

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the update for issues regarding page tab resizing they just pushed today: https://developers.facebook.com/live_status/ – you should look if there are any bug reports regarding your problem already, and if not open a new one.

Comment: I saw that and thought it might have something to do with it.   I tried submitting a bug today too, but it keeps telling me I have to add Tags to my bug report, which of course I did. :(